# How to Implement Logansquare TypeConverter in Inner json object class

Tags: android, json, typeconverter, jsonparser, logan-square

My Question is How to Implement Logansquare Custom TypeConverter class in the Inner Json object class.

This is my model class :

```
class CommunicationParser{

    @JsonField
    public String MSG;
    @JsonField
    public int DATA_ID;
    @JsonField
    public ArrayList<Records> RECORDS;

    @JsonObject
    public static class Records {
        @JsonField
        public String REC1;
        @JsonField
        public String REC2;
        @JsonField
        public int REC_VALUE;

      @JsonField   // Error occur when apply annotation
        public communication COMMUNICATIONACTION;  //MAKE ERROR IN THIS LINE

    }

    @JsonObject
    public static class communication {
        @JsonField
        public PrimaryAction PRIMARYACTION;
        @JsonField
        public ArrayList<SecondaryAction> SECONDARYACTION;
    }

    @JsonObject
    public static class PrimaryAction {
        @JsonField
        public int ID;
        @JsonField
        public String TITLE;
    }

    @JsonObject
    public static class SecondaryAction {
        @JsonField
        public int ID;
        @JsonField
        public String TITLE;
    }
}
```

How to Implement Logansquare Custom TypeConverter class in the Inner Json object class? kindly give me a solution..

Thanks in Advance

Comment: *Error occur when apply annotation* - what error? Update your question with full error message (as text)

Comment: This Error message appear..




"com.bluelinelabs.logansquare.NoSuchTypeConverterException: Class com.recordapp.model.api.entity.CommunicationParser.Records does not having a TypeConverter defined. TypeConverters can be added using LoganSquare.registerTypeConverter()."